# Hide or Show singleton?

Tags: java, c#, design-patterns, .net

Singleton is a common pattern implemented in both native libraries of .NET and Java. You will see it as such:

C#:    `MyClass.Instance`

Java: `MyClass.getInstance()`

The question is: **when writing APIs, is it better to expose the singleton through a property or getter, or should I hide it as much as possible?**

Here are the alternatives for illustrative purposes:

Exposed(C#):

```
private static MyClass instance;
public static MyClass Instance
{
    get {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new MyClass();
        return instance;
    }
}

public void PerformOperation() { ... }
```

Hidden (C#):

```
private static MyClass instance;

public static void PerformOperation()
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        instance = new MyClass();
    }
    ...
}
```

**EDIT:**
There seems to be a number of detractors of the Singleton design. Great! Please tell me why and what is the better alternative. Here is my scenario:

My whole application utilises one logger (log4net/log4j). Whenever, the program has something to log, it utilises the `Logger` class (e.g. `Logger.Instance.Warn(...)` or `Logger.Instance.Error(...)` etc. Should I use `Logger.Warn(...)` or `Logger.Warn(...)` instead?

If you have an alternative to singletons that addresses my concern, then please write an answer for it. Thank you :)

Comment: The "hidden" variant reminds me of https://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/singleton-considered-stupid

Comment: I have an even better suggestion: [Avoid Singletons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)

Comment: @delnan I'm reading through the post. Informative so far.

@w4rumy I am not a big fan of "never use..." or "never do...". There is a time and place for everything (as long as it's OOP). In my _application_, I have a log4net/log4j logger. I've created a class called `Logger`, and had been wondering whether to provide `Logger.Error("")` or `Logger.Instance.Error(...)` functionality. The native libraries all use Instance (e.g. `AppDomain`), but I feel that it's a bit superfluous.

Comment: @w4rumy thank you for the link. I don't actually agree with the statement that Singletons have to be entirelly avoided. Just like any design patterns, there are situations where they are optimal solutions and situations where we should better try something else. If we try nailing with a screwdriver, no wonder that we will end up hating all screwdrivers :)

Comment: @Sinker - until different modules need different logging behaviors...  Never use singletons.

Comment: @Sinker: Singleton is a strange thing - first time you see it it looks like a great idea, then you get your first doubts and think better to use it seldom (or just when it seems to have "its place"), but after experiencing its drawbacks you come to a point where you think "Oh dear, if I had known this before, I would have never used this pattern in the first place".

Comment: @Telastyn please clarify. I don't understand what you mean. I thought the whole point of a singleton was to have all modules use the same instance of the class, regardless.

Comment: @DocBrown, you sound lie you've been at that point that you speak of. I think that my scenario (3rd comment down on this question) is a good case for using singletons.

Comment: @sinker - it is, and restricting all of your modules to a common insance is a **terrible** idea. Modules very often want different implementations. Requirements very often shift to need variations in the modules (we want to now log things to the network except for network errors). Tests very often want different instances. Concurrency becomes complex with shared instances. Reuse becomes neigh-impossible. And on and on. Just do a search, I've commented here personally a ton about it. Singleton anti-pattern should provide even better arguments.

Comment: Best practice for using it, if your have to: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think hiding Singleton is a bad idea. If you don't have a way to get a reference to the created instance via a `getInstance()` method, how you are going to do it considering that Singleton classes do not have `public` constructors? There is no way to get that reference. That means that if you decide to "hide" the Signbleton, your only option is to check in every `public static` method of the Signletone class whether the instance was already instantiated and if not, do it. So your code becomes something like this:

```
class BadSingletone {
    private static MyClass instance;

    public static void PerformOperation()
    {
        if (instance == null) { instance = new MyClass(); }
        ...
    }

        public static void PerformSomeOtherOperation()
    {
        if (instance == null) { instance = new MyClass(); }
        ...
    }

    public static void PerformYetAnotherOperation()
    {
        if (instance == null) { instance = new MyClass(); }
        ...
    }
}
```

littered with all those instantiation checks. You can of course encapsulate the check in a separate function but you will again have to call it in every `public static` function of the class. And what if you accidentially forget to include it in one of the functions? Users of the class will not be too happy about it.

So, to my mind, hiding Singleton does not make sense - it makes you litter your code with unneccessary checks.

Comment: Nice answer. I don't have enough reputation to vote-up :(

Comment: @Sinker that you for the assesment of my little efforts. You can still show your appreciation by formally accepting it :)

Comment: I'll give people the chance to answer too :)

Comment: :) fair enough.

Comment: Playing devil's advocate: Couldn't one create a `private static` property or method which takes care of this, much like when the instance isn't hidden?

Comment: I covered that scenario in my answer. You can encapsulate the checking logic in a separate method, but then you will have to call this method in every public static method of your class to make sure that the instance has been instantiated and not get NullPointerException. So in fact this does not change anything and does not decrease programmer's burden.

Comment: I'm talking about something like `private int counter = 1; public static int NextID() { return Instance.counter++; }` where `Instance` is the property that hides that. It adds an unnecessary `Instance.`, sure, but not an extra line and you'd have to actively use the underlying field to get a NPE. How do you assume that method to be written?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, I don't believe it's still considered a singleton pattern unless you expose the instance to other classes.  It's just a private static member.  That being said, in general the smaller the scope of a variable, the better.  If other classes don't need it, don't share it.  However, in most cases it's going to be much simpler just to instantiate the static member at declaration instead of checking everywhere if it's already been instantiated.

Comment: I guess what you're saying is the test is whether the other objects need to work with the _instance_ directly, right?

Comment: That's right.  Most oriented design principles are easier to differentiate by looking at the *calling* code.

Comment: Well if both Sun and Microsoft use that design, I guess it's worth considering! I never considered why that might be the case, but your point goes some way to explain the mentality.